# Display Square in Html

Tags: css, knockout.js

I have a requirement where in I have to display a list of square shape and below books sales in last 4 weeks and based on the value of sale, color will be displayed in square using knockout dynamically.
[image]

What is the best way to achieve this view?

Comment: What have you tried? This is really not that hard and is easy to find as well.

Comment: There's quite a few problems in your question (you should really read through the help center), but above all: do you realize *that sample picture doesn't show **squares** but non-square rectangles (of different sizes)*? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Html squares pls try as below

```
<div id="squares">
    <div id="square1"></div>
    <div id="square2"></div>
    <div id="square3"></div>
</div>
```

and CSS as below

```
#squares div {
    /* these styles will let the divs line up next to each other
       while accepting dimensions */
    display: block;
    float: left;

    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;


    /* a small margin to separate the blocks */
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#square1 {  background: red;}
#square2 {  background: black;}
#square3 {  background: yellow;}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is how to make squares

```
<div id="square"></div>    
#square {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
    }
```

hope that helps
source: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I am facing one more issue i have 

                <h1> <p> <div id="square"/> </p> </h1>

Problem is square is overlapping h1 tags .. When i see source html content is as below


                            <h1> <div id="square"/>  <p></p> </h1>

Comment: see this demo http://jsfiddle.net/m696uq22/1/. you want something like this?